# using mongo aggregation how to get records with count

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation

I am try this code past 24 hours records i got it but my requirement is all past 24 hours records and total count of records

```
db.getCollection("COLLECTION_NAME").find({"createdAt":{$gt:new Date(Date.now() - 24*60*60 * 1000)}})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer would've been more precise if you could provide 2,3 collections to test this query. Anyways, this is how you do it with `aggregation` framework.

```
db.collection.aggregate(
[
   {$match : {"createdAt":{$gt:new Date(Date.now() - 24*60*60 * 1000)}}},
    { "$group": {
        "_id": null, 
        "data": { "$push": "$$ROOT" }, 
        "count": { "$sum": 1 }
    }},
    { "$unwind": "$data" },
    {  "$project ": {"_id" : 0}}
]
)
```

Comment: @ George Baileyany    possible same query but get only count value and create Date

Comment: you better have a look at [$project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/)

Comment: Baileyany {  "$project ": {"createdAt" : 1}} is write or not

Comment: `{ "$project ": {"createdAt" : 1, count : 1}}`

Comment: glad it was helpful. have fun

Answer (score 0):

The total récords count in a collection Is

db.getCollection("myCollection").count()

Comment: @ Hector Martinez    .count using only total records count but my expected output past 24 hours record with count any suggest me

Comment: i need both outputs past 24 hours records and count of records

Comment: collection.find({}).toArray(función(error,docs){ var count = docs.length;})

Comment: Or with the cursor object i think it would be collection.find().count(). Obviously in find you put your query.

Comment: any possible write aggregate only not using functions

Comment: using .count i got the the answer but i expected output not only count .cout with view the records